# 2 versions of Metropolis-Hastings : are they equivalent?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I have seen 2 different versions of Metropolis algorithm.

**First one :**

[image]

**Second one :**

[image]

I don't understand the differences between the 2 versions, especially in the second one where I have to use the probability $a$.

Anyone could tell if both versions are equivalent and if yes, how they are correlated ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two versions are equivalent. In version 2, you accept the proposed value with probability $\min(a, 1)$. In version 1, you accept the proposed value if $U<a$. Since $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$, the probability of the event $\{U<a\}$ is exactly $\min(a, 1)$, and so the algorithms are the same.